# Variance Ratio Test shows mean-reverting trend but Hurst exponent is greater than 0.5

Tags: time-series, trends, hurst-exponent

I believe Hurst Exponent greater than 0.5 indicates persistent series, meaning the values are not mean-reverting. However, when I run a variance ratio test, I get a graph clearly showing mean reverting trend and I don't quite know how to interpret this information.
Which one should I believe and why do I get this result?

Comment: Andrew Lo wrote an article about how the Hurst-Mandelbrot test for lg term dependency could be misleading (false positive)  if there is sh term dependency. You will find it as Chapter 6 in his book Non-Random Walk down Wall Street available online. It is quite advanced and I don't remember well the details (I had to read it in school years ago) .